AzurePowershell@5 fails to initialize: "Access to the path 'Global\AzurePowerShellConfigInit' is denied"
I have a situation with our self-hosted (Windows) Azure DevOps agent.
The vm runs two agents - Yes I know it's not recommended but I thought I could pull it off as we don't use very resource-intensive workloads, ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#can-i-install-multiple-self-hosted-agents-on-the-same-machine.
Sometimes, I guess it's when two jobs try to start an AzurePowershell task (but it's hard to investigate that), I get the Access to the path 'Global\AzurePowerShellConfigInit' is denied. error.
I though that maybe using separate Powershell installations per user would solve my problem, but then I found this reference in https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/Accounts/Authentication/AzureSessionInitializer.cs which makes me think the "Global" mutex would still block me?

Any ideas for a workaround, or should I simply forget the multiple agents when using AzurePowershell task?
pipeline log:
Starting: my_powershell_task
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
Version      : 5.242.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azurepowershelltroubleshooting
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'E:\Agent_2\_work\_temp\5866d915-908c-494a-9f28-3baef6eda200.ps1'"
Added TLS 1.2 in session.
Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules\Az.Accounts\2.13.1\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
##[error]Access to the path 'Global\AzurePowerShellConfigInit' is denied.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope CurrentUser -ErrorAction Stop
##[warning]INITIALIZATION: Fail to access profile file and will try to use process ContextAutosaveSetting mode. Detailed error: 'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ResourceManager.ProtectedFileProvider' threw an exception.'
##[warning]Run Connect-AzAccount to login.
Finishing: my_powershell_task


Do you mean that the issue exists when the VM has two agents? If the VM only enable one agent, will it work? And can you confirm if other tasks have the similar issue?

We have the exact same problem. Our admins also added two agents on one VM. Not best-practice, but they want to save expenses. And our pipelines regularly fail because of this.

I have created a Github issue for this at the Azure Powershell project. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/25701

@KevinLu-MSFT yes, exactly, problem appears for example for pipelines which launch multiple jobs "simultaneously" on agents (on the same vm).

It seems that the issue is related to the limitation of the Azure PowerShell task itself. I suggest that you can report the issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues This is the pipeline task feedback site.

@KevinLu-MSFT Not so sure about that. The failing mutex code, that’s referenced in this post and in my GitHub issue, is part of Az PowerShell itself. It could happen for other concurrent Powershell processes

I've also created an issue at the Azure Pipeline Tasks Github: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/20245
